# Structure and class hierarchy (making template)

Tags: c++, oop, templates

I have structures `Aa`, `Bb`, `Cc`, which inherit one common structure `ABC` and classes `A`, `B`, `C`, which inherit structures `Aa`, `Bb`, `Cc`. Each of them contains virtual methods. There is a common part and "unique" part in classes `A`, `B`, `C`. Here is a code:

```
#include <iostream>
using namespace std;

struct ABC {
    virtual ~ABC() {
    };
    virtual void printABC() = 0;
    virtual void someMethod() = 0;
};

struct Aa: ABC {
    virtual void printA() = 0;
};

struct Bb: ABC {
    virtual void printB()=0;
};

struct Cc: ABC {
    virtual void printC()=0;
};

class A: public Aa {
public:
    A() {
    }
    virtual ~A() {
    }
    //unique part
    void printA() {
        cout<<"A!"<<endl;
    }
    //common part
    void printABC() {
        cout<<"ABC"<<endl;
    }
    void someMethod() {
        cout<<"ABC!"<<endl;
    }
};

class B: public Bb {
    public:
    B() {
    }
    virtual ~B() {
    }
    //unique part
    void printB(){
        cout<<"B!"<<endl;
    }
    //common part
    void printABC() {
        cout<<"ABC"<<endl;
    }
    void someMethod() {
        cout<<"ABC!"<<endl;
    }
};

class C: public Cc {
    public:
    C() {
    }
    virtual ~C() {
    }
    //unique part
    void printC(){
        cout<<"C!"<<endl;
    }
    //common part
    void printABC() {
        cout<<"ABC"<<endl;
    }
    void someMethod() {
        cout<<"ABC!"<<endl;
    }
};
```

It seems to be not optimal. Is it possible to make template for `A`, `B`, `C` and how? Or, maybe, it's better to make new class with all common methods within or make hierarchy.  Suppose, we cannot change structures: ABC, Aa, Bb, Cc, but we can change classes A, B, C. Which method is more elegant and how to realize it better?

Comment: Why is this "common part" not included in the common base class `ABC` ?

Comment: Just implement `printABC` and `someFunction` in `ABC` (instead of just providing the interface) and you are done.

Comment: Suppose, I have one more .cpp and there are G, H, J classes, which need another printABC and someMethod, for instance,  cout<<"GHJ"<<endl;. Suppose, we cannot change structures: ABC, Aa, Bb, Cc, but we can change classes A, B, C.

Answer (score 2):

It depends on how you will use your structures and which kind of polymorphic behavior you need.

if your willing is to handle A B C objects from ABC pointers so then you truly need this hierarchy 
for example : if you have and array of ABC pointers pointing to different A B C objects .

if you only have a common code within different class then templates will be better and a single function will be enough for you treatment

```
template <class X>
void someMethod (X object) {
}
```

And if you cannot change ABC ,Aa ,Bb ,Cc structure then you don't have other choice then to use hierarchy .

Answer (score 1):

Stuff the common code into a dedicated base class:

```
struct ABC_CommonCode
{
    //common part
    void printABC() {
        cout<<"ABC"<<endl;
    }
    void someMethod() {
        cout<<"ABC!"<<endl;
    }
};

class A: public Aa, public ABC_CommonCode
{
    ...
};

class B: public Bb, public ABC_CommonCode
{
    ...
};
```

This will work if the real code in `printABC` doesn't need access to members of your classes. However, your code is just an example, and your real code is probably more complicated than that. If `printABC` needs to work with an instance of `class A`, you can use e.g. delegation:

```
template <class A_or_B_or_C>
struct ABC_CommonCode
{
    static void printABC(A_or_B_or_C& object) {
        cout << "ABC = " << object.GetABC();
        // 100 lines of other code
    }
};

class A: public Aa
{
    // common part
    // repeated in each class, but it's just 3 lines of code
    // regardless of actual implementation
    void printABC() {
        ABC_CommonCode<A>::printABC(*this);
    }
};
```

You might also want to read about [CRTP](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Curiously_recurring_template_pattern), but I am not sure it's warranted here.